# Particle emitter not displaying during rendering

Tags: rendering, color, layers

I am trying to create a donut by following Blender Guru on youtube. The render was working fine but suddenly the icing of the donut is has become invisible.

While modelling:
[image]

After rendering:
[image]

Can somebody please help me find a solution?
I am using blender 2.81a

file:
[image]

Comment: If you could provide a .blend file someone could likely easily see the problem.

Comment: How do I add the .blend file?
I am new here

Comment: Upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the text

Comment: The title of this question have very little to do with the actual question. Please change it to something more relevant.

Comment: I am new here. I don't know how to put my question across. Please help to frame a problem statement. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the particle settings of the icing -> Render -> Check "Show Emitter"

Comment: Hii... Thanks a lot for the help!
I thought it was a bug in the version!

Thanks and regards,
Raghunandan V